# Finding out the ARC length

Tags: geometry

[image]
From the given info we can say that DCA and BAC angles are equal. But  will this angle be helpful to link with the center?  If I add a line with the center, the angle will be  unknown.

Do we have to evaluate the area first to get the arc length ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : We can calculate the arc lengths of $CB$ and $DA$ and then subtract that from the circumference. Since $r=8$, so arc $CB=\dfrac{8\pi}{2}$. And just as you said $\angle DC=\angle BAC$, so arc $DA=\dfrac{8\pi}{2}$. Now you may calculate the rest.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The arc $BC$ (that is, the angle $BOC$) is twice the angle $BAC$ and equal to the arc $DA$. See the [inscribed angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).